# MySQL: What is the maximum number of cores used by a single MySQL server?

Tags: mysql

What is the maximum number of cores used by a single MySQL server in a production setting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MySQL server can use any [1] number of cores. But remember that a single connection/query will only use one thread. So while MySQL supports many core the queries are processed on one core each.

- [1] wrt. recent technology.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend you MySQL 5.5 -- add [this manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/smp-improvements.html) and [licence page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/license-google-smp-patch.html) and this [benchmark](http://code.google.com/p/google-mysql-tools/wiki/SmpPerformance) together and you will see why. To clarify further: MySQL -- rather, the InnoDB storage engine -- will use all cores in the system but up until 5.4 it actually slowed down with a higher number of cores, Google fixed this and the first MySQL to contain it is 5.5.

This fix also can be found in the [1.0.4 plugin](http://code.google.com/p/google-mysql-tools/wiki/Mysql5Patches) and newer which can be [enabled](http://www.chriscalender.com/?tag=innodb-plugin) in MySQL 5.1.38.